# Area of region enclosed by the locus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the area of region enclosed by the locus of $z$ given by $\arg(z-i) - \arg(z+i)= \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and imaginary axis (where $i= \sqrt {-1}$)

What I did was I put $$\tan (\alpha) =z-i$$ and $$\tan (\beta) = z+i$$ and solving for $\tan(\alpha-\beta) $ I got the locus of $z$ as $xy=\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}$ but now how to find area?
[image]

Comment: Did you not get any bounds on x or y?  The area between that hyperbola and the x and y axes, for all positive x and y, is infinite.

Comment: @user247327 That is problem what I am facing I think my locus is wrong

Comment: Hey did you get something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that, in this question, the principal value of the argument is chosen to be the unique value of the argument that lies within the interval $(−\pi,\pi]$. Then, since, for any $z$ for which $\arg(z\pm i)$ are defined, $\arg(z-i)-\arg(z+i)\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$ holds, there is no $z$ such that $\arg(z-i)-\arg(z+i)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ (for the details, see the end of this answer).

This suggests that the question defines the range of the principal value as being in the closed-open interval $[0, 2\pi)$.

Let $z=x+yi$ where $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Then, we have
$$\arg(x+yi)=\begin{cases}2\pi-\arctan(\frac{-y}{x})&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\arctan(\frac yx)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$}
\\\frac{3}{2}\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=0$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 0$}
\\\pi+\arctan(\frac{-y}{-x})&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\leqslant 0$}
\\\pi-\arctan(\frac{y}{-x})&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\gt 0$}
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\arg(x+yi)=\begin{cases}2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y}{x})&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\arctan(\frac yx)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$}
\\\frac{3}{2}\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=0$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 0$}
\\\pi+\arctan(\frac yx)&\text{if $x\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$

Since we have
$$\arg(x+(y-1)i)=\begin{cases}
2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant 1$}
\\\frac{3}{2}\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt 1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=1$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 1$}
\\\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)&\text{if $x\lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\arg(x+(y+1)i)=\begin{cases}
2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant -1$}
\\\frac{3}{2}\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=-1$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt -1$}
\\\pi+\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$
we get
$$\arg(x+(y-1)i)-\arg(x+(y+1)i)$$
$$=\begin{cases}
2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})-(2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x}))&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})-\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $-1\leqslant y\lt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant 1$}
\\\frac{3}{2}\pi-\frac{3}{2}\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=-1$}
\\\frac{3}{2}\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $-1\lt y\lt 1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=1$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 1$}
\\\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-(\pi+\arctan(\frac{y+1}x))&\text{if $x\lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

$$=\begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})-\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})\lt 0&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})-\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)\gt 2\pi&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $-1\leqslant y\lt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)\lt 0&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant 1$}
\\0&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=-1$}
\\\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $-1\lt y\lt 1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=1$}
\\ 0&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

So, under the condition $x\lt 0$, we have
$$\arctan\bigg(\frac{y-1}x\bigg)-\arctan\bigg(\frac{y+1}x\bigg)= \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
i.e.
$$\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2-y^2}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{3},$$
i.e.
$$\frac{2x}{1-x^2-y^2}=-\sqrt 3,$$
i.e.
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2\tag1$$

Since the region we seek is the inside of the circle $(1)$ with $x\lt 0$, the area is given by
$$\pi\bigg(\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\bigg)^2\times\frac{\frac{2}{3}\pi}{2\pi}-\frac 12\bigg(\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\bigg)^2\sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigg)=\color{red}{\frac{4}{9}\pi-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}}$$

---

In the following, let us prove that if the principal value of the argument is chosen to be the unique value of the argument that lies within the interval $(−\pi,\pi]$, then, for any $z$ for which $\arg(z\pm i)$ are defined, $\arg(z-i)-\arg(z+i)\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$ holds.

*Proof* :

Let $z=x+yi$ where $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

If the principal value of the argument is chosen to be the unique value of the argument that lies within the interval $(−\pi,\pi]$, then we have
$$\arg(x+yi)=\begin{cases}\text{arctan}(\frac yx)&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$}
\\-\arctan(\frac{-y}{x})&\text{if $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 0$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=0$}
\\-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\pi-\arctan(\frac{y}{-x})&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$}
\\-(\pi-\arctan(\frac{-y}{-x}))&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\arg(x+yi)=\begin{cases}\text{arctan}(\frac yx)&\text{if $x\gt 0$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\gt 0$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=0$}
\\-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y}{x})+\pi&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$}
\\\arctan(\frac yx)-\pi&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Since we have
$$\arg(x+(y-1)i)=\begin{cases}\text{arctan}(\frac{y-1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $1\lt y$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=1$}
\\-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})+\pi&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $1\leqslant y$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\pi&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\lt 1$}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$\arg(x+(y+1)i)=\begin{cases}\text{arctan}(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $-1\lt y$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=-1$}
\\-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})+\pi&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $-1\leqslant y$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)-\pi&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\end{cases}$$

we get
$$\arg(x+(y-1)i)-\arg(x+(y+1)i)$$
$$=\begin{cases}\text{arctan}(\frac{y-1}x)-\text{arctan}(\frac{y+1}x)&\text{if $x\gt 0$}
\\-\frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{2})&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=-1$}
\\-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $-1\lt y\lt 1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=1$}
\\\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x=0$ and $1\lt y$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\pi-(\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)-\pi)&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\pi-(\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})+\pi)&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $-1\leqslant y\lt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})+\pi-(\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})+\pi)&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $1\leqslant y$}\end{cases}$$

$$=\begin{cases}\text{arctan}(\frac{y-1}x)-\text{arctan}(\frac{y+1}x)\lt 0&\text{if $x\gt 0$}
\\0&\text{if $x=0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=-1$}
\\-\pi&\text{if $x=0$ and $-1\lt y\lt 1$}
\\\text{undefined}&\text{if $x=0$ and $y=1$}
\\0&\text{if $x=0$ and $1\lt y$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\arctan(\frac{y+1}x)\lt\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $y\lt -1$}
\\-2\pi+\arctan(\frac{y-1}x)-\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})\lt 0&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $-1\leqslant y\lt 1$}
\\\arctan(\frac{y-1}{x})-\arctan(\frac{y+1}{x})\lt\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if $x\lt 0$ and $1\leqslant y$}\end{cases}$$

Therefore, we can say that, for any $z$ for which $\arg(z\pm i)$ are defined, $\arg(z-i)-\arg(z+i)\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$ holds.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: I am getting answer  as $\frac{4\pi}{9}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {3}}$. Because angle at center will be $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and radius is $\frac{2}{\sqrt {3}}$ So area of sector will be $\frac{\pi r^{2} \theta}{2\pi}-\frac{r^{2} sin (\frac{2\pi}{3})}{2}$ where $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$. I think you have calculated area of major arc but i think locus will be minor arc.

Comment: I am adding an image in question it self so that I don't ask separate question. If it violate stack exchange guidelines then i'll remove.

Comment: @mathophile : I think that my answer has some errors. I'll rewrite my answer when I have time. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Because I was getting $\dfrac{-\pi}{3}$ for $z=\sqrt {3}$

Comment: @mathophile : You are correct, and so I rewrote my answer. I didn't know that the question defines the range of the principal value as being in the closed-open interval $[0, 2\pi)$.